# Отследить сообщение 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel5

Подскажите пожалуйста использую Laravel в связке с Vue.js, когда выходит и сессии то если выполняется запрос выдает `401 Unauthorized` и только после перезагрузки страницы меня перебрасывает на ввод логина и пароля
Можно ли отловить при каждом запросе это и если будет `401 Unauthorized` выдать сообщение что Сессия закончилась, войдите заново

Comment: А как вы выходите? И как вы авторизовываетесь

Comment: Через штатную авторизацию

Comment: Тогда удаляйте токены со фронта, и меняйте стейт приложения на неавторизованный если у вас спа